# Is it possible to config output toString() in pattern of logback?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I would like logger to output `toString()` of calling class instance. And I don't want to send it explicitly by

```
log.info("{}: message", this.toString());
```

but I want to code

```
log.info("message");
```

and have some pattern configured in `logback.xml`.

Is it possible?

Comment: In general, is it possible for a method in Java to access methods from its caller? Think about that and you'll have the answer.

Comment: Logback allows to output method name, with `M/ method` pattern. Can't find the pattern for instance toString.

Comment: You don't need the `.toString()` part. That will happen automatically.